# How do I define a callback function in an outer scope using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I've this code:

```
for (i in namespaces) 
{
    namespaces[i].on('connection',handleConnection(namespaces[i]));  

    function handleConnection(ns)
    {

        return function (socket){//connection

                    socket.on('setUsername',setUsernameCallback);//event received

                    function setUsernameCallback(userN){//I want to move this 
                       socket.username = userN;
                       //some code
                         }

                };
    }

}
```

In order to make my code easier to read, I want to make `setUsernameCallback` function defined in an outer scope or maybe in another JS file, like that:

```
for (i in namespaces) 
{
    namespaces[i].on('connection',handleConnection(namespaces[i]));  

    function handleConnection(ns)
    {

        return function (socket){//connection

                    socket.on('setUsername',setUsernameCallback);//event received

                };
    }

}




 function setUsernameCallback(userN){
                           socket.username = userN;
                           //some code
                             }
```

Actually, this is not working.  I tried different ways to pass parameter but I'm still getting **undefined socket**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define it like bellow

```
var setUsernameCallback = function(socket){
    return function(userN){
        socket.username = userN;
        //some code
     }
}
```

And pass the `socket` to function so it will be accessible

```
socket.on('setUsername',setUsernameCallback(socket));//event received
```

Comment: what the benefit i get if i give a name to the anonymous function ?  thx

Comment: I don't know any benefits if there are any.